# IF statement inside variable and other IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this code:

```
while($s<$nrpi)
{
    if(${checkpart.$s}=="0") {
        $parts.="<div>".${part.$s}." = ".${price.$s}."</div>";
    }    
    $s++;
};
```

I want to include an IF statement for checking the `${price.$s}`.
So if the variable has the value 0, i don't wan't to display the "=" sign, nor the variable, just `${part.$s}` inside div.
**I'm looking for the most compact solution**, because in reality the code is much larger. Thanks!

Comment: Most compact solution as a `key-value array`.

Comment: the ternary operator `?:`is your friend. http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: variable variables? stop using those. you'll just end up tearing out whatever hair you have left trying to debug problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a ternary operator :

```
$parts.= "<div>".${part.$s}.(${price.$s}?" = ".${price.$s}:"")."</div>";
```

Ref http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary